# Unending booting kernel

Tags: debian, kernel

My notebook is a Asus N56VZ. I am using Debian 8 with LXDE Desktop Envoirment. Yesterday, i tried to install nvidia driver.

I run a few of codes for preinstallation of driver. ( https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers )

```
aptitude install linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64 build-essential

init 3
```

After that i install .run file. But i couldn't. It said that I should do this without X Window. I gave up for this method.

So, I decided to apt-get install `nvidia-driver`. I did so, it says reboot the PC for installation done perfectly.

Now, My computer coundn't end up boot screen.

[image: Unending Boot, stays in that point eternally.]

What sould i do?

Answer (score 1):

Boot with a DVD/bootable USB pen and clean up the driver. Depending on the installation method it should be under

```
/lib/modules/your_kernel_version/updates/dkms
```

or

```
/lib/modules/your_kernel_version/kernel/drivers/video
```

Or alternatively, boot with the same version you are using, mount it, chroot and deinstall the package.

Keep two different kernel versions installed to have an alternate kernel to select in `grub` while experimenting with the kernel.

Comment: It didn't work out.

Comment: Maybe it corrupted something else. Easiest way out may be apt-get reinstall linux-image-* with a chroot